# A name for 'lax' colimit for poset-valued functors?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, limits-colimits

Let $F,G\colon C\to \mathsf{POS}$ be functors, where $C$ is a category and $\mathsf{POS}$ denotes the category of posets and monotone maps.

By a *lax* natural transformation $\alpha\colon F\Rightarrow G\colon C\to\mathsf{POS}$ I mean an $\mathsf{Ob}(C)$-indexed family $(F(c)\xrightarrow{\alpha_c}G(c))_c$ of monotone maps such that for each $f\in C(c,d)$, $G(f)\circ\alpha_c\leq \alpha_d\circ F(f)$, where $\leq$ stands for the point-wise order relation (induced by $G(d)$).

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a poset. By a *lax* cone with base $F$ to $(X,\leq)$ is meant a lax natural transformation $\tau\colon F\Rightarrow \Delta(X,\leq)$, where $\Delta(X,\leq)\colon C\to \mathsf{POS}$ is the usual diagonal functor with constant value $(X,\leq)$.

Finally I call *lax* colimit of $F$ a pair $((X_F,\leq_F),q^F)$, where $(X_F,\leq_F)$ is a poset and $q^F\colon F\Rightarrow \Delta(X_F,\leq_F)$ is a lax cone with base $F$ to $(X_F,\leq_F)$ such that for any other lax cone $\tau\colon F\Rightarrow \Delta(X_F,\leq_F)$, there is a unique monotone map $t\colon (X_F,\leq_F)\to (X,\leq)$ such that for each $C$-object $c$, $t\circ q_c^F=\tau_c$.

In other words the definition of the *lax colimit* for a poset-valued functor is the same as the definition of its usual colimit except that ordinary cones are replaced by *lax* ones (that is, equality is replaced by inequality).

I imagine that there is a standard terminology for this kind of notions. But can someone tell me?

Comment: Er, if you know about lax natural transformations then you must also know there already are notions of lax cone and lax limit… right? (These are standard terms in 2-category theory.)

Comment: @Zhen Lin, I don't know about lax natural transformation : I just chose the name because it seemed to me to be appropriate (so I am lucky if it is the right name!). Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Well, it seems you are doubly lucky, since you got the direction correct for the definition of "lax natural transformation", but not lucky enough to get the direction correct for "lax colimit". (There is some arbitrariness for these definitions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Pos}$ is a slightly degenerate example of a 2-category, where there is at most one 2-morphism between any parallel pair of 1-morphisms: explicitly, given $f, g : X \to Y$, we have a 2-morphism $f \Rightarrow g$ if and only if $f (x) \le g (x)$ for all $x \in X$.
Thus, we may apply notions from 2-category theory to $\textbf{Pos}$.

Given 2-categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ and 2-functors $F, G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$, a **lax natural transformation** $\alpha : F \Rightarrow G$ is an assignment of a 1-morphism $\alpha_X : F X \to G X$ for each object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and a 2-morphism $\alpha_f : G f \circ \alpha_X \Rightarrow \alpha_Y \circ F f$ for each 1-morphism $f : X \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, such that for every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $\alpha_{\textrm{id}_X} = \textrm{id}_{\alpha_X}$, and for every composable pair $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to Z$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $\alpha_g G f \bullet F g \alpha_f = \alpha_{g \circ f}$, i.e. $\alpha_{g \circ f}$ is equal to the following composite 2-morphism:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F X @>{\alpha_X}>> G X \\
@V{F f}VV \overset{\alpha_f}{\Leftarrow} @VV{G f}V \\
F Y @>{\alpha_Y}>> G Y \\
@V{F g}VV \overset{\alpha_g}{\Leftarrow} @VV{G g}V \\
F Z @>>{\alpha_Z}> G Z
\end{CD}$$
In the special case of $\textbf{Pos}$ this agrees with what you have defined.

A **lax limit** of a 2-functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ weighted by a 2-functor $J : \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Cat}$ is an object $L$ in $\mathcal{D}$ equipped with a universal lax natural transformation $J \Rightarrow \mathcal{D} (L, F {-})$, i.e. a representation of the 2-functor $\textbf{Lax} (J, \mathcal{D} ({-}, F))$.
Specialising to the case where $J$ is the constant $1$, we get the notion of a **lax conical limit** of $F$.
A bit more explicitly, a **lax cone** over $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is an assignment of a 1-morphism $\lambda_X : L \to F X$ for each object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and a 2-morphism $\lambda_f : F f \circ \lambda_X \Rightarrow \lambda_Y$ for each 1-morphism $f : X \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, such that for every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $\lambda_{\textrm{id}_X} = \textrm{id}_{\lambda_X}$, and for every composable pair $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to Z$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $\lambda_g F f \bullet \lambda_f = \lambda_{g \circ f}$, i.e. $\lambda_{g \circ f}$ is equal to the following composite 2-morphism:
$$\begin{CD}
L @>{\lambda_X}>> F X \\
@| \overset{\lambda_f}{\Leftarrow} @VV{F f}V \\
L @>{\lambda_Y}>> F Y \\
@| \overset{\lambda_g}{\Leftarrow} @VV{F g}V \\
L @>>{\lambda_Z}> F Z
\end{CD}$$
A lax conical limit of $F$ is then an object equipped with a universal lax cone over $F$.

Where things get tricky is where you dualise.
A **lax colimit** of a 2-functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ weighted by a 2-functor $J : \mathcal{C}^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Cat}$ is an object $L$ in $\mathcal{D}$ equipped with a universal lax natural transformation $\lambda : J \Rightarrow \mathcal{D} (F {-}, L)$.
Unfolding, that means we have a functor $\lambda_X : J X \to \mathcal{D} (F X, L)$ for each object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and a natural transformation $\lambda_f : \mathcal{D} (F f, L) \circ \lambda_Y \Rightarrow \lambda_X \circ J f$ for each 1-morphism $f : X \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, satisfying various equations.
Specialising, we find that a **lax cocone** under $F$ is an assignment of a 1-morphism $\lambda_X : F X \to L$ for each object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and a 2-morphism $\lambda_f : \lambda_Y \circ F f \Rightarrow \lambda_X$ for each 1-morphism $f : X \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that etc.
This is *not* the same thing as a lax natural transformation from $F$ to the constant $L$!
Instead, a lax natural transformation from $F$ to a constant is an **oplax cocone** under $F$.
Thus, what you have defined is the notion of an **oplax conical colimit**.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by $\mathbf{Lax}(J, \mathcal{D}(-, F))$? I'm not sure this expression typechecks, as $J\colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Cat}$, and I can't make sense of $\mathcal{D}(-, F)$ but it doesn't look like it has this type.